# Looking for Windows GUI test tool like Selenium for web testing

Tags: windows, user-interface, testing

We use and like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to test our web user interfaces.  Now we need to test a native Windows program and are looking for a similar tool.  Something that can record a session to an editable script that can be replayed to execute the test.  I've seen vague references to Spy++ and UI Automation Verify but nothing that looks close to what I'm looking for.  Am I missing it or doesn't such a product exist?  Open source, like Selenium, would be great but this is important enough we'd pay for the right tool.  Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium is to Web UI testing as ________ is to Windows application UI testing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1137448/113116) and [Tools for automated GUI testing (on Windows)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/120359/113116)

Comment: Explore WinRunner, TestComplete, Silk test, QTP. Most should support desktop applications as well.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up with Win32:GuiTest for Perl.  It doesn't record but it does play nicely.

Answer (score 0):

THere are a large number of automated testing tools that can be used to drive windows interfaces: Microsoft Test Manager, Quick Test Pro from HP as well as open source solutions such as White from Codeplex

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom code. I would suggest you look at below article for WCF, WPF, Web Services Testing

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/cc301096

Alternatively code plex has few tools Guia - Graphical User Interface Automation 
http://guia.codeplex.com/

Please check.