# web page layout

Tags: html, css

well.. there are questions similar to this topic but i wasnt able to find one that could answer my query.

my questions:

1. if u open a web page and press Ctrl+A the whole page gets selected and is in blue. What information can be extracted from this selection about the layout of the page?
2. Any automatic testing tool that i can use to test the website layout? Just give the website URL and it parses automatically all the pages and reports potential mistakes/errors in the CSS/HTML? i think Selienium has such functionality but I am looking for something much simpler.

Comment: You could try the W3C Validator, that's pretty funky-ish: http://validator.w3.org/ and for C.S.S: http://jigsaw.w3.org/ - Unless I completely mis-understood your query?

Comment: no. im not talking about css,html validators. my main concern is that the layout is consistent across different browsers

Comment: There is something called Tellurium ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tellurium_(software) ), which is hosted on Google Code, but it's just like an addon that goes ontop of Selienium, maybe that might make it a little simpler?

Comment: #2 is interesting.. theoretically we could take screenshots from different browsers, align them, and then highlight the differences. but i've never seen that done.

Answer (score 4):

if you are looking for consistency across different browsers, you can check [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/).
It gives you a snapshot of your site layout across all famous browsers on all Operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

1-All major browsers would allow you to copy the general visible text, But FireFox can only copy the IMG alt [img alt="this value"]

2-As @βӔḺṪẶⱫŌŔ mentioned validator.w3.org is the ultimate place for validating HTML.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you paste the content of the selection, (ctrl + A) on an editor, you will find that all the text content which is on the page will be pasted. Any images or other elements other than text will not be pasted. So that would not give you much information regarding the layout.
2. Selenium is widely regarded as beginner friendly. You can also look at a few others like [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/w/).Find a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251989/looking-for-windows-gui-test-tool-like-selenium-for-web-testing)