# Automated GUI Testing

Tags: java, swing, testing, netbeans, gui-testing

I am writing a Java Desktop Application (SWING) using Netbeans IDE 6.9. I want to do automated GUI testing. All I know about testing is JUnit tests which won't apply for my GUI application. Is there a particular testing framework I can use for testing the GUI application, are there good ones out there? Which ones are easy to use (I need to do testing but I don't have a lot of time for that, however, I don't want to ignore that). My application is basically one frame, with three to 4 tabs (not a big one), my tests shouldn't be complicated, so is there a simple framework that will let me test my application fast and in a strong way to find bugs?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137448/selenium-is-to-web-ui-testing-as-is-to-windows-application-ui-testing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend the following open source tools (we are using them on our Java Swing applications):

- [UISpec4J](http://www.uispec4j.org/) - Non visual testing tool, very good for unit testing/TDD for the GUI application
- [Abbot](http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml) - Is good for functional testing. Also have record & playback

You can use both or either one of them

From the commercial tools in my opinion the best is IBM [Rational Functional Tester](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/tester/functional/) - it supports Java applications very well. However it is expensive and is focused on the record & replay approach which is not very reliable.

Comment: None of the two you mentioned appears [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools). I would consider both projects dead.

Comment: @malat Considered that the answer is more than 5 years old it is likely to happen

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am surprised to see there's no driver to support testing Java GUI applications with Appium. Oracle is a big company, they can easily spend some money on this.

Answer (score 8):

You can try "fest".

http://code.google.com/p/fest/

Comment: FEST is indeed a very good UI testing library (although it doesn't have a recording feature yet). One important thing to do to make its use easier (probably the same for other testing libs) is to explicitly uniquely name each component in your UI.

Answer (score 3):

[QF-test](http://www.qfs.de/index4.htm)

Answer (score -5):

Try [**Selenium**](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [**Watij**](http://watij.com/).

Both frameworks open a web-page in browser and manipulate page elements. They can click a page element, enter data to input field, get a text or HTML of a specified element, etc. Watij in addition to that can emulate javascript events directly.

Comment: But they will not work for the desktop applications