# Testing Java Desktop Application with MVC Architecture

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, desktop-application

I would like to ask is there a way to create automated tests for Java Desktop Application . I see there are a lot of tutorials for WEB however I would like to test the GUI and the functionality  application.

What are the options to test the functionalities ?(such as Login which is writen in MVC style)

Thank you

Comment: Potentially duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415441/automated-gui-testing

Comment: I have checked the anawers but They dont really answer my questioms or the links don't work