# Been asked to use Selenium to test Windows desktop application UI--how is this possible?

Tags: windows, user-interface, selenium, desktop

A company I applied to had sent me a "test", which I had to decline, due to it not making a lot of sense: They asked me to use Selenium to test a  Win desktop app GUI and produce bug reports in the table form. They claimed that they're using Selenium to test Win desktop applications in their company, but they wouldn't tell how.

I did some research, and my understanding is that Selenium works with web browsers only, as it's been specifically designed for this. How can it connect to Windows desktop app? I just don't see any way possible for this. I found a claim that some integrate it with another open source tool to do this, but this "test" was supposed to take 1 hour of my time and installing some other framework, configuring, integrating with Selenium, etc, etc definitely wouldn't fall into one hour time frame. I had heard from another company too, that they wanted me to use Selenium to automate non-browser stuff if they hired me... Still have no clue about this--is this even possible? -- or is it something simply wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to test a windows desktop UI using Selenium.  Selenium uses javascript to perform UI actions.  Here's a link that discusses Windows UI test products.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137448/selenium-is-to-web-ui-testing-as-is-to-windows-application-ui-testing

Comment: I agree: I thought it was actually a trick question, but they were serious about using Selenium for this. And this was C# application--didn't have access to its source either, it was fully black box. Selenium doesn't make any sense here. Thanks

Comment: I am a little confused by that. I can only assume a few things: they may be expecting you to say "hang on, Selenium doesn't "do" Windows UI applications (WinForms, WPF etc)" or there is some tool that builds on top of Selenium that no one appears to know about (possible).

Comment: Arran, no they did SERIOUSLY MEAN to test Windows UI with Selenium. When I told them it's not possible, they declined my candidacy immediately. Perhaps, this is just a "clueless tech recruiter" case.

Comment: Take a look at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137448/selenium-is-to-web-ui-testing-as-is-to-windows-application-ui-testing

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.** Selenium can only automate web browsers, and even then, only certain browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera, and occasionally Safari).  It interacts with them at a very deep level, very specific to the browser in question, in ways that don't apply to other Windows applications.

Comment: I had another interview, where the technical lead told me that the successful candidate will automate their non-web stuff (things like a bunch of RESTful service endpoints talking to each other, etc), via Selenium. I'm always suspicious about technical competence of the interviewer themselves when these things are suggested, considering the latter case can be automated using some simple  scripts without any existing "framework" and Selenium is really only meant to work with Javascript-executing browsers. Why use a car to sail across the lake, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is meant for GUI tests of web applications and nothing else. But you can include Sikuli in webdriver code and can test the any of the applications either desktop or web applications, since it uses Image recognition.

else if you want to test the desktop application using Selenium thne u need to import [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and can test those as well